# In Jupyter notebook, how to change auto indent to tab instead of 4 spaces

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just started using jupyter notebook. Google search didn't help. Thanks!

**Update: Quick Summary of answers**

Running the following code in a cell before you start a ipython file got the task done for me. One problem is that we have to run this everytime for each file.

```
    %%javascript

    // apply setting to all current CodeMirror instances
    IPython.notebook.get_cells().map(
        function(c) {  return c.code_mirror.options.indentWithTabs=true;  }
    );

    // make sure new CodeMirror instances created in the future also use this setting
    CodeMirror.defaults.indentWithTabs=true;
```

Comment: Putting `{
    "Editor": {
        "codemirror_options": {
            "indentWithTabs": true
        }
    }
}` into `etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` does not work - strange.

Comment: 1. If you have an answer to your problem, don't edit the question to put it; instead post an answer separately (if you they the existing answers are insufficient)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run this javascript code in a cell it should allow you to insert hard tabs:

```
%%javascript

IPython.tab_as_tab_everywhere = function(use_tabs) {
    if (use_tabs === undefined) {
        use_tabs = true; 
    }

    // apply setting to all current CodeMirror instances
    IPython.notebook.get_cells().map(
        function(c) {  return c.code_mirror.options.indentWithTabs=use_tabs;  }
    );
    // make sure new CodeMirror instances created in the future also use this setting
    CodeMirror.defaults.indentWithTabs=use_tabs;

    };

IPython.tab_as_tab_everywhere()
```

It works for me. Source = http://pirsquared.org/blog/indenting-tabs.html

Comment: Do I have to do it every time I open a ipynb file?

Comment: I have tried putting this in ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js and ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js : After putting in both the locations I restarted the notebook and still see that the tabs are shown as spaces :(

Comment: @VarunJanga you should put this code into a cell in your current ipython notebook and run that cell, and yeah it has to be done for every file. It's not a perfect solution by any means but a good hack to accomplish what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, It's working after I run it in a cell.

Comment: (cc @VarunJanga ) It does work if you put it in custom.js. It just doesn't convert the **existing** leading spaces to tabs; however converting exist spaces is a different question.

Answer (score 3):

In JupyterLab 2.0+:

[image]

For those visually impaired:
`Settings` > `Text Editor Indentation` > `Indent with Tab`

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to swap spaces for tabs in [Jupyter's text editor plugin](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/packages/fileeditor-extension), then you can just switch the "insertSpaces" flag to false in the Advanced Settings Editor.

```
{
    "editorConfig": {
        "insertSpaces": false
    }
}
```

Comment: In one is for jupyter lab, not jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, add a key `CodeCell.cm_config.indentWithTabs` with value `true` in `nbconfig/notebook.json` (in the jupyter configuration directory).

So, for example the `notebook.json` should look like this:

```json
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentWithTabs": true
    }
  }
}
```